# Reading memory in memory-protected OS

Tags: memory, operating-system

Modern operating systems and CPU hardware provide memory protection that prevent processes from accessing memory other than that allocated to the process.

Given this, how would one write a utility like Windows' Resource Manager that reports how much memory is free, in use, reserved, etc.; or a basic memory dump utility and the like? Is the only way to do this on such systems through making such a program part of the operating system with kernel privileges?

There are operating system APIs that can allow access to another process' memory. But even if you use these, your memory-reading program still needs privileges. Is going through the OS the only way to find out the contents of memory and CPU registers?

Is the situation similar with disk monitoring programs?

Answer (score 0):

Memory is a bunch of individual labeled memory locations, which are either a 1 or 0, a high or low, on or off.  these are bits.
It takes a certain amount of current to use these bits, turning them on or off, so maybe it is possible you could read how much current the memory is using, find your minimums and maximums to set benchmarks, and see memory usage by how much the current varies.

it would be quite the task to do this with software.  It is on the kernel level or even upstream of that.

With disk monitoring systems, the actual number of bits coming from and going to are counted.

Comment: that would require elaborate monitoring hardware built into the computer hardware. Interesting idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Given this, how would one write a utility like Windows' Resource Manager that reports how much memory is free, in use, reserved, etc.; or a basic memory dump utility and the like?

Such applications call system services in the operating system to get such data. These may be either documented or undocumented.